# Merge SQL INSERT with Reference Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I need to synchronize two tables.

**TableA**

```
Id    Name
```

**TableB**

```
Id  Name RefID --It's a Foreign key, defined as primary key in Table "TableReference"
```

**TableReference**

```
RefID -- Identity Column, auto increment
```

I need to merge `TableA` and `TableB` in such a way that on each insert in `TableB`, a value should be inserted into `TableReference` and that inserted value should be copied into `RefId` column of `TableB`.

What I am doing?

I am using SSIS hence I need to have a SSIS based solution OR SQL based solution. I know how to merge tables using Merge SQL command but I am not able to insert a value into `TableRef` and copy it back to `TableB`. Could not figure out how i can accomplish this. SQL user-defined functions don't allow `INSERT` so I can't use it.

```
Merge TabaleB T
Using Table A S
On S.Id=T.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
T.ID=S.ID,
T.NAME=S.NAME

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN

INSERT(S.ID,S.NAME, {Somehow here i need a function call that inserts in TableRef and   Returns SCOPE_IDENTITY})
```

The problem is T-SQL functions don't allow `INSERT` and a stored procedure can't be called here as `Merge` doesn't allow any TSQL thing other than `INSERT` after `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to add a `TRIGGER` on your TableB.  If so, one option would be to use the `INSERTED` row and go from there.

Maybe something like this (untested):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_TableB
ON dbo.TableB
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT TableReference  DEFAULT VALUES;  

    DECLARE @RefId INT;
    SELECT @RefId  = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    UPDATE t1
        SET t1.RefId = @RefId 
    FROM dbo.TableB AS t1 
        INNER JOIN INSERTED AS i
            ON i.Id= t1.Id

END
GO
```

Good luck.

Comment: Trigger runs only Once when i execute MERGE SQL. It does not run for each row.

Comment: You are correct -- wasn't sure with using MERGE.  Alternatively, the INSERTED table should still store all results from the MERGE.  While I'm not a fan of using a CURSOR in Triggers (or for that matter much at all), you could probably loop through the INSERTED table and insert/update accordingly.  Just a thought.